# Integrating Alfresco Share in external web app

Tags: share, alfresco, portlet, cmis, integrate

I have a project ( a web application ) that aims to integrate Alfresco Share like a portlet on it. Something like what's done in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=On7SfssX8TI&t=22s. If anyone please know where do I start ? What should I do and what steps to follow, I'll be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share and Alfresco Repository communicate via REST APIs. Share pulls/fetches data from Alfresco Repository by making calls to its APIs.

So, if you want to use Share as front-end with your Web Application then you would have to create necessary APIs that handle documents and its metadata within your web application and provide them to share when needed.

In most of the cases, web-application is used as front-end instead share and Alfresco repository can be used as server-side repository to maintain the server-side operations on documents. In this, you have to develop only client-side APIs that can communicate with Alfresco Repository to exchange data.

So my advice to you is, study the Alfresco-share with Repository first and then try to use share with your web-application.

Comment: Share as front-end ( as client-side ) it's exactly what I want to do. I already searched how the Share communicates with Repository using REST APIs. And right now i'm searching how to communicate Share (as a client-side) with my app (as a server-side) using CMIS. Is there some configuration to do, or an existant Share connector or I must develop a connector between Share and my app. Thank you very much for replying.

Comment: I searched and I found what you said, it will be difficult to develop conector between Share and my server app since it was developed for Alfresco Repository. I'm searching now how to communicate my server app with Repository, so that Share can expose my documents since it communicates with Repository. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Liferay to create easily your portlet, you can check this addon [Alfresco Portlet For Liferay Portal](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-portlet-liferay-portal-alfstore) , or google "alfresco liferay", there is many examples of integration

Comment: But if I created it with Liferay, it stays in Liferay isn't it ? I'm new in those technologies, if you can explain to me how to proceed please. My goal is to get the Alfresco Share functionality into my app in order to explore my documents, and if there is a way to explore those documents in Alfresco Share from my app without really bringing them into Alfresco server.